# Changing the default 302 HTTP->HTTPS redirect to 301

Tags: google-cloud-run

Have a client running a website on Cloud Run and post-release 2 issues came up:

1. CR uses a default 302 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS - is there any way of changing those to 301 permanent redirects (temporary redirects are a rather poor choice for SEO)
2. I know it's not possible to remove the Cloud Run assigned URLs like *.a.run.app, but is there any hack for adding a noindex directive on them (either via meta tags or the HTTP response header - but those would need to apply to *.a.run.app URLs, and not the custom production domain)? Alternatively, adding a separate /robots.txt file only for *.a.run.app URLs?

I was told a dev tried adding code to noindex the *.a.run.app URLs but that did not work due to Cloud Run's limitation itself.

I would appreciate any help on these two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both of these can be achieved in your application code.

Check [this article](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-https-part-2/) for HTTP redirection implementation.

As for noindex it should also be possible to determine request host and then respond with [X-Robots-Tag header](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#xrobotstag) to disable indexing.